# Ace Editor Handle Marker Events

Tags: ace-editor

I'm trying to take some actions when sitting on top of a marker in Ace Editor based on keydown operations.

However, it looks like I'm unable to trap events on markers using simple jquery hookups.

I declare my markers like this:

```
var marker =session.addMarker(range, "misspelled", "typo", true);
```

end then try to hook up events like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown',".misspelled",
     function (e) {
            //if (e.keyCode == 93)
            alert('show popup here');               
        });
```

No matter what I do I can't get events to fire on the marker elements.

I set up a jsbin example here:
http://jsbin.com/xowaledobi/5/edit?html,output

and used a click to make it easier to play with. When clicking on the marker - nothing happens. Looking at the DOM I can see the marker and my custom style:

[image]

And based on selecting that node it looks like it is accessible via the UI, but still I can't seem to fire any events on it. Neither click or keydown cause anything to happen.

So - what's the best way to capture key events in a Ace Editor marker?

ps
In another part of the application I use a right click pop up handler and there I am using rather expensive code that maps the marker id and location to the current mouse position. It works ok for mouse ops, but is too way too slow to do for keyboard operations.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use jquery to work with dom elements inside the editor, you need to use editor api like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #e1 { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 50%;
        left: 0;
    } 
  .misspelled {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  tfa
<div id="e1">&lt;xml>
  function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
  }
&lt;/xml></div>
<pre id="e2">
second editor
</pre>

<script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script> 
<script>
    var Range = ace.require("ace/range").Range
    var editor = ace.edit("e1");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    editor.session.addMarker(new Range(1,0,1,20),"misspelled","fullLine",true);

    editor.on("click", function(e) { 
      if (e.getDocumentPosition().row == 1)
         alert('clicked'); 
    });
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it does work, just not reliably :-) The problem is not how to handle events - either approach works for that, the problem is trying to get a hold of the marker that's active and capturing events on that. Either jQuery or the Editor events handle clicks and keydown, just not on the markers.

Comment: e.getDocumentPosition() allows to check if the click was inside a marker